# Extract stings between a delimiter if it matches a certain string

Tags: linux, grep, sed

File
cat hosts.cfg

```
define host {
            host_name                             switchlan
            alias                                 switchlan
            address                               192.168.2.1
            icon_image_alt                        Switch
            icon_image                            base/switch40.gif
            statusmap_image                       base/switch40.gd2
            check_command                         check-host-alive
            check_period                          24x7
            notification_period                   24x7
            contact_groups                        +admins,noc-monitor
            use                                   generic-switch
}
define host {
            host_name                             localhost
            alias                                 localhost
            address                               127.0.0.1
            icon_image_alt                        Linux
            icon_image                            base/linux40.gif
            statusmap_image                       base/linux40.gd2
            check_command                         check-host-alive
            use                                   linux-server
            contact_groups                        +admins
}
```

In the above I need to extract the IP address and hostname of the host when the "use" value is "Switch"

My current approach:

```
tr '\n' '\t' < hosts.cfg | sed s/}/}\\n/g |  sed 's/ \+ /,/g' | grep generic-switch lt4 | awk -F "," '{print $3 $ 7}'
```

1. Remove new line char.
2. Add new line again at the end of the definition when ever we see "}" .
3. Replace white spaces with "'".
4. Find the line with string "generic-switch".
5. Print only the hostname and IP address.

I assume there is a better approach. Please suggest alternatives / optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl would be a good choice here: that config file has a syntax compatible with Tcl:

```
$ cat parsehosts.tcl
proc define {name data} {
    array set host $data
    if {[string match {*switch*} [string tolower $host(use)]]} {
        puts "$host(host_name) $host(address)"
    }
}
source [lindex $argv 0]

$ tclsh parsehosts.tcl hosts.cfg
switchlan 192.168.2.1
```

So, in bash, you chould say

```
read hostname address < <(tclsh parsehosts.tcl hosts.cfg)
echo $hostname
echo $address
```